# GAE webapp2 delete all UserTokens (drop all sessios) for specific user

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to drop all user sessions when user resets his password, but I can't find a way to do that.
My idea was to get all UserTokens of the specific user and delete them, but it seems impossible, because of

```
user = model.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
```

in UserToken model

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two ways how to do that.

First is to inherit from the `UserToken` class making `user` an indexed property. Then you can set the `token_model` class property to your new token model in your user class. Here is the code:

```py
class MyToken(UserToken):
    user = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class MyUser(User):
    token_model = MyToken
    # etc.
```

Don't forget to set the user model used by webapp2 to your user class if you do not do it already:

```py
webapp2_config = {
    "webapp2_extras.auth": {
        "user_model": "models.MyUser"
    },
    # etc.
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, config=webapp2_config)
```

The second way is to make a complicated datastore query based on the token key name. Since the key names are of the form `<user_id>.<scope>.<random>`, it is possible to retrieve all the entities starting with a specific user ID. Have a look at the code:

```py
def query_tokens_by_user(user_id):
    min_key = ndb.Key(UserToken, "%s." % user_id)
    max_key = ndb.Key(UserToken, "%s/" % user_id)  # / is the next ASCII character after .
    return UserToken.query(UserToken.key > min_key, UserToken.key < max_key)
```

This uses the fact that the query by key names works in the lexicographical order.